# Android Studio fragment - onButtonPressed method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

When creating a new fragment with Android Studio, it generates the method onButtonPressed(Uri), how should you hook it into a UI event, say a click on a button declared in an xml? How is this method intended to be used?

```
// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments get attached to activity, the `onFragmentInteraction` is a call back method that your activity use to interact with the fragment

For example, the following activity implements the interface from  your fragment

```
public static class YourActivity extends Activity
        implements YourFragment.onFragmentInteraction{
    ...

    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
        // Do something with uri
    }
}
```

But as the `TODO` suggest

> // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event

Feel free to adapt it to your need or delete it if not needed. example:

```
mYourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: But why does the fragment need a button listener with a URI rather than the traditional onClick listener with a view?

Answer (score 2):

I found the other answers to be a touch vague as a noob myself. Meda points out that the fragment is attached to the activity, the docs state it is more of an extention to it. Personally I feel it's more proper to state that the `FRAGMENT` instance encapsulates an `ACTIVITY` instance.

Let's consider the code for each component; that is the `INTERFACE`, `ACTIVITY`, `FRAGMENT` and finally the `LAYOUT`.

> ***Note :*** *I'm using Kotlin so there is a chance some of this is getting rewired in the background when it is transpiled into Java, though this seems unlikely.*
>
> #### Interface
>
> Names the `CALLBACK` specifying it's signature.
>
> ```
>  interface ConcessionSelection {
>          fun selectConcession(view : View)
>  }
> ```
>
> ***Note :*** *I've moved the interface into it's own class, so the activity is declared as  `class ACTIVITY : AppCompatActivity(), INTERFACE` instead of  `class ACTIVITY : AppCompatActivity(), FRAGMENT.INTERFACE`*
>
> #### Activity
>
> Provides the logic for the `CALLBACK`.
>
> ```
>  class ACTIVITY : AppCompatActivity(), INTERFACE {
>      ...
>      override fun CALLBACK  (view: View) {
>          Log.i("ACTIVITY:CALLBACK","Activity Callback")
>      }
>      ...
>  }
> ```
>
> #### Fragment
>
> Makes provision for a listener and attaches or detaches such instances during the execution of the application.
>
> ```
> class FRAGMENT : Fragment() {  
>
>     private var listener: ACTIVITY? = null
>     ...
>     override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
>         super.onAttach(context)
>         if (context is ACTIVITY) {
>             listener = context
>         } else {
>             throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener")
>         }
>     }
>     override fun onDetach() {
>         super.onDetach()
>         listener = null
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> #### Layout
>
> Specifies the `CALLBACK`
>
> ```
> <...>
> ...
> <Button
>         android:id="@+id/button"
>         android:text="Button"
>         android:onClick="CALLBACK"/> # Usually highlighted in red by IDE since this is resolved at runtime.
> ...
> </...>
> ```
>
> ***note :*** *This is the layout file for the fragment not the activity, I don't show the activities file as it's not relevant.*

If you've looked at the code carefully you will notice there isn't a `CALLBACK` set upon the `FRAGMENT`, rather it is set upon the `ACTIVITY` instead. The `FRAGMENT` delegates the call from the `onClickListener` to it's `listener`, which happens to be the `ACTIVITY`, during operation. This confuses the Android IDE somewhat as it is not smart enough to realize that the `CALLBACK` belongs to the listener, that is the `ACTIVITY` implementing the `INTERFACE`, and it highlights the relevant XML accordingly. In fact setting a `CALLBACK` upon the fragment gets ignored unless one takes additional steps to trap the relevant signals e.g. I believe `ListFragment` does this to redirect to `onItemSelected`.

The example `onButtonPressed` provided by the template appears to simply be just that and does not provide a very useful implementation. Perhaps there is a tutorial on the android site that explains how to trap events and redirect to this method.

Answer (score 0):

for example, you has a Button named button:

```
button.setOnClickLisenter(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        // process and construct uri
        Uri uri = null;
        onButtonPressed(uri);
    }
};
```

You also can try other style to use onButtonPressed.